# How to make a site adapt to sizes of phone and iPad screens?

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad

I am working on a new website and have put a set width into my css file.  I have a requirement to make the site adaptable and resizable to fit the smaller screens of phones and various tablet devices.

What in my css styles has to be set so that the site best adapts to the other screen sizes?

Comment: Look into Responsive Design as has been metioned in an answer. A good primer on the subject is http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use media queries. This is the whole basis behind responsive design.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* write smartphone styles here */
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
    /* tablets in portrait mode */
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    /* tablets in landscape mode and smaller/older monitors */
}
```

Take a look here:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Comment: Ah ok so the website itself can still be set to some static width, right?

Comment: It depends on your approach. In this way, yes, you can have a static width for your container, and then just overwrite that width in your media queries ( make sure media queries are listed last - and in reverse order ).  Otherwise, you can go the "mobile first" route ( http://www.abookapart.com/products/mobile-first ) and define the smaller screen first and then adapt to larger screens. The trick is to know what and when to overwrite to get the layout you want. The jist is that you can alter your site to fit any screen (as long as the browser supports media queries).